# problems with Crypt::SSLeay and using HTTPS request?

Tags: perl, https

I'm trying to connect to a website via HTTPS, by sending a WWW::Mechanize get request and whenever I try and run my script I get this error:

> This Application has faile to start because libeay32_.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem

And inside the command prompt I get:

> Error GETing http...: can't load 'C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.dll for module Crypt::SSLeay: load_file: The specified module could not be found (Crypt::SSLeay or IO::Socket::SSL no installed) at ...

I don't understand the problem because I'm very new to programming with Perl. Crypt::SSLeay is installed, the .dll is in the proper location and IO::Socket::SSL is also installed, or whenever I try to install it via cpan i get the libeay error again. The libeay32_.dll is located in the C:\straberry\c\bin. I don't have full access right to the computer because I am doing this from work. If someone could explain to me the reason for the problem it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it really saying "Cryot" in the Path of "SSLeay.dll"? Also: Is "C:\straberry\c\bin" in the PATH-environment variable?

Comment: I put it in the path but I still get the errors

Comment: After you have put it in the path you have to close the explorer window (better: all open explorer-windows) or the cmd-window since they keep the old environment-variables until the process is newly started. Maybe it's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make an answer out of my comments so you can check this question as answered:

- Add `"C:\straberry\c\bin"` to the `PATH`-environment variable
- Close the explorer- and/or commandline-windows since running processes aren't notified if the environment changes and thus keep the old environment active (okay, in the command line you could apply the update manually by `set PATH=...new path...`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [README.SSL](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.02/README.SSL) file that comes with LWP? (WWW::Mechanize uses LWP to make the actual HTTP requests).

Comment: Okay so I tried to install LWP::Protocol::HTTPS and I got a similar warnings, ...libeay32_.dll...